# DOCKER manifest unknown from local Docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, helm3

I have been reading a lot of posts about this but according to them I should have my bases covered so I am not sure what is going on.

I am using Minikube, Docker, Helm, and a local Docker registry on a Mac.  After I install with Helm I see the following error.

```
Failed to pull image "127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

My deployment spec looks like this.

```
spec:
    containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 5000
            protocol: TCP
```

I get this if I try to pull the image.

```
$docker pull 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0

v1.0: Pulling from hello-world
Digest: sha256:0534fcc8d406574f7def33e726f0e476ce94866e21d8cbd6ed4c273de113e9d3
Status: Image is up to date for 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0
127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0
```

Then I check the manifest and it exists.

```
$curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:5000/v2/hello-world/manifests/sha256:0534fcc8d406574f7def33e726f0e476ce94866e21d8cbd6ed4c273de113e9d3

{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": 8102,
      "digest": "sha256:49188cd9fa7002b28391f01ba5c0ce4328cc467abeb6743d181cbe1a3a2fd37c"
   },
   ...
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**Edit:**

The exact commands I executed are as follows

- docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
- docker build . -t hello-world:v1.0
- docker tag hello-world:v1.0 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0
- docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0
- helm install hello-world ./hello-world

**Edit With Resolution:**

I finally got it to work.  I had to modify the image key in the podspec of the pod/deployment manifest to `host.minikube.internal:5000/hello-world:v1.0` as suggested in the thread with @zsolt.  Secondly I had to start minikube with `--insecure-registry="host.minikube.internal:5000"` instead of `--insecure-registry="127.0.0.1:5000"` while executing `minikube delete` before this change.  Thanks for the assistance @zsolt!

Comment: Minikube, each individual pod, the registry, and the host all think 127.0.0.1 points at something different.  Should the registry address be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable registry addon in minikube:

`minikube addons enable registry`

Also you can enable alias for registry:

`minikube addons enable registry-aliases # test.com, test.org, example.com, example.org`

Docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/deploy/addons/registry-aliases/README.md

**UPDATE:**

I just reread you question, you want to reach from minikube the registry that is running on your host machine. For that you can use the `host.minikube.internal` hostname, so `host.minikube.internal:5000/hello-world:v1.0`

Docs: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/

Comment: I already did that.  Before I did that I was getting some other connection error instead of "manifest unknown"

Comment: check the [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/deploy/addons/registry-aliases/README.md), I just run through it and it works, the helloword pod is using the image built into the example.org registry (running inside minikube):`example.org/demo/helloworld:f4f6b051...`

Comment: Thanks.  I will check out that example.  I just made an edit to the post with the exact commands I am executing.

Comment: @chutcher see my update in answer

Comment: I got the sample app deployed and operational and I see what it is doing.  It is adding an internal minikube registry and deploying from there.  What I am trying to accomplish is to have a registry outside of minikube using docker registry

Comment: I just saw your update.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Yes, I can ping successfully the docker registry from minikube shell

Comment: @chutcher cool so, did this resolve your issue?

Comment: No.  Although I can ping from the shell I still get the manifest unknown error and not a network error.  I can shut down the local registry and still get the manifest unknown error.  I would think I would get a network error at this point, so I suspect it is trying to go to an outside registry and not the local one

Comment: But did you change the image in the pod spec from  `127.0.0.1:5000/hello-world:v1.0` to `host.minikube.internal:5000/hello-world:v1.0`

Comment: Ah wait a minute, you don't have to do `docker pull` inside minikube ssh. You just modify the image key in the podspec of your pod/deployment manifest to `host.minikube.internal:5000/hello-world:v1.0` and it will work.

Comment: Yes, it is a little better now.  It seems to be able to get to the registry but now it is showing "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client".  I've added "insecure-registries" : ["127.0.0.1:5000"] to daemon.json and I am starting minikube with  --insecure-registry="127.0.0.1:5000".  I'll look into it more on Monday

Comment: And it works!  Thanks a ton for the help!  The final piece was to start minikube with `--insecure-registry="host.minikube.internal:5000"` instead of `--insecure-registry="127.0.0.1:5000"`.  I tried this on Friday but the reason it didn't work then was because I did not run `minikube delete` between the change, which is a must.

Comment: @chutcher great, good to hear!